# ComboBoxItems cannot be selected properly?

Tags: c#, wpf, controls

I got a problem with one of my application's `ComboBox`es.
I have a method that sets a `List<T>` as the `ItemSource` of `ComboBox cmbCombo`.
For a quick test I created two items whose `CategoryName` - Properties (of type `string`) are "B" and "TH".
Now if I set the `DisplayMemberPath="CategoryName"` everything works fine but if I try to select "B" nothing happens. There is no problem with selecting "TH" but "B" doesn't work.
I figured out that I have to hover exactly over the text "B" in order to get it selected. The "TH" item gets selected even if I hover over the blank area of the item.

Here is an extract of my source where `ComboBox.ItemSource` is being set but I don't think that there is any error:

```
List<MissionCategory> categoryList = MissionCategoryHandler.MissionCategoryList;
cmbMissionCategory.ItemsSource = categoryList;
cmbMissionCategory.DisplayMemberPath = "CategoryName";
cmbMissionCategory.Background = Brushes.WhiteBrush;
```

As you can see I set the `Background` to WhiteBrush ( a `SolidColorBrush` with #FFFFFFFF). I thought that it might help because it helped in other cases to not leave the background transparent (e.g. when trying to drag usercontrols) that the application doesn't grasp at nothing :) unfortunately this didn't solve my problem.

Is there any way to fix this?
Thanks in advance!

Edit: I just noticed that the "TH"-item doesn't get selected properly too sometimes :(

Comment: Putting a DataTemplate in your ItemsTemplate with a TextBlock that is large and the background is not null should fix the problem.

Comment: Do you overwrite the `ItemTemplate` in your XAML anywhere? It sounds like you may have overwritten it with something that does not stretch the entire width of the ComboBox, or that has a transparent background so does not register hit tests.

Comment: I don't use XAML in my current project so is isn't overwritten.